# EC2 Instance : Access RDS via Alias Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Is it possible to set up RDS in such a way that EC2 instances use the RDS Instance Identifier "mydb" to connect to RDS instead of using the public DNS name : `mydb.cfnr64hlvtcp.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`. ?

Answer (score 5):

The only way to access an RDS database is by using the public DNS endpoint name generated by RDS when the database is created.

You could setup your own CNAME for the RDS DNS name if you wanted to hide the public DNS name from a component in your system, but then you must maintain that entry, which seems a bit complicated.

AWS strongly recommends that you don't use the IP address behind the RDS DNS entry directly since that IP may change, for example if your database has to failover to a new instance. [1]

[1] http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#What_is_a_DB_Subnet_Group_and_why_do_I_need_one

Comment: >>> but then you must maintain that entry, which seems a bit complicated.

It's significantly less complicated than changing the RDS URL in each of your apps when it changes. I highly recommend using the CNAME.

Answer (score 3):

AWS has documentation for creating RDS CNAME's:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-rds-db.html

Comment: [This page got deleted in December 2021](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-route53-docs/commit/fb0fe0b2bca24b8da6c6f14e3a836ce6fe0edb88#diff-0f4de185389337f203b2861761601aeef19744b13c2e1384c58a8d1965bb7aed).

Comment: @ankon did you find where they moved the information? i'm looking now for this same thing...

Comment: I think the idea is that you don't actually do this anymore. If I should guess about the reason: It breaks SSL hostname verification, which you probably want to do.

Note that you can read the contents of the page on the link I posted. Use "Load diff" if Github doesn't show the contents of the "routing-to-rds-db.md" file.